# Google Analytics scope question

Tags: google-analytics

I'm studying GA and and want to know if it is possible to save any custom information. For example I have a lot of checkboxes on the page and want to know checked statistics. I mean checks count for each checkbox separately. I see it in the following way: before postback I'm getting all checks information and send it to GA :).

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Analytics javascript API to send this information to google, possibly as an [event](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). This can happen whenever you choose, such as before form submission.

Comment: Hmm, I need to save checkboxes' names. So the only possible way to save it is to add event for each checked checkbox. If it is 20 checkboxes checked it maybe big loading. Hmm, maybe not as it will work asynchronously.

Comment: Can't you encode all 20 checkbox values into a single value, and send that in one go?

Comment: Sure I can. But how they will separated in GA?

Answer (score 1):

You can make events to each of the checkboxes, individualize them if you want, and see the results in "event tracking" in contents.

More info about event tracking from 
[google analytics docs](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerOverview.html)